# C# - Possible to use Subinacl or something else (an api maybe?) from C# code?

Tags: c#, api

I've created a program in C# which creates users and adds them to groups, everything is working fine. But I also want to create a "home folder", which is on another server, and the share will be like this: 81file01/users/username. And of course set the rights of the folder to the newly created AD-user. Now we're using a vb-script to do this, and this part is done with Subinacl, but is there a way to do this through my c# code?

I'm using .net 3.5 by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can shell out using `System.Diagnostics.Process` and just call Subinacl directly as you do now.

Or you roll your sleeves up, and get your hands dirty calling what appear to be mainly a Win32 set of APIs.  The [friendliest article on that subject I could find from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163832.aspx) talks about using the COM interface via COM interop.

There are some [wrappers to these APIs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ntsecuritynet.aspx) floating around, but how good they are, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks!
I found an example:

using System.Security.AccessControl;

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

               DirectorySecurity dSecurity = di.GetAccessControl();

               FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule("users", FileSystemRights.Modify , InheritanceFlags.None | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, ControlType);

               dSecurity.SetAccessRule(rule);

               di.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

I'm trying this now, don't know if it will work though..

Comment: And what about Powershell?
I'm going to have to use Powershell later to create mailbox for the user as well...hmmmm